# What is the speedup between x86 and MIPS for different programs?

Tags: performance

Suppose

> Computer A executes the MIPS ISA and has a 2.5GHz clock frequency. Computer B executes the x86 and has a 3GHz clock frequency. On average, programs execute 1.5 times as many MIPS instructions than x86 instructions.
>
> 1. For Program P1, Computer A has a CPI of 2 and Computer B has a CPI of 3. Which computer is faster for P1? What is the speedup?
> 2. For Program P2, Computer A has a CPI of 1 and Computer B has a CPI of 2. Which computer is faster for P2? What is the speedup?

Comment: @phuclv: the x86 and mips tags are basically irrelevant here.  The architecture names might as well be FizzyRISC and BuzzyCISC, because the average CPI numbers are given in the problem.  Nothing about real x86 or MIPS performance applies; they're just examples of ISAs that typically take fewer or greater instructions to get the same amount of work done for this math problem.  Thus the title is totally misleading as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following shows how to setup the equations (only).

> Computer A executes the MIPS ISA and has a 2.5Ghz clock frequency ("cycles per second"). Computer B executes the x86 and has a 3GHz clock frequency. On average, programs execute 1.5 times as many MIPS instructions than x86 instructions.

```
M_instructions_per_seconds = (M_cycles_per_second / cycles_per_instruction)
```

Example:

> a) For Program P1, Computer A has a CPI of 2 and Computer B has a CPI of 3. Which computer is faster for P1? What is the speedup?

```
mips_A_p1 = (2500M cycles/sec) / (2 cycles/instr) = 1250M instr/sec (1250 MIPS)
```

Note how "cycles" cancels out to leave "instr/sec".

Answer (score 0):

Speed up= 1.5*1250/1000.

Which will result in 1.875